# How do i get the new Password stored in my firebase realtime database in android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I just realized that when I press the forgot password in my app and change the password the password is not changed in the realtime database.Is it possible to change the realtime database as well?
This is my  forgot password page code

```
public class ForgotPassword extends AppCompatActivity {
    
    EditText useremail;
    Button password;
    FirebaseAuth auth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_forgot_password);
        useremail=findViewById(R.id.enterEmailAddress);
        password=findViewById(R.id.sendpassword);
        auth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        password.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(useremail.getText().toString()).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            Toast.makeText(ForgotPassword.this,"Password sent to your mail",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        else{
                            Toast.makeText(ForgotPassword.this,task.getException().getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

this is the value stored in my database

```
{
  "Users" : {
    "Driver" : {
      "S04QBZx3PxYaLfDWBC3j3otM5ml1" : {
        "mail" : "m.yusuf7423@gmail.com",
        "password" : "1234567",
        "username" : "YUSUF"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @MohammedYusuf do you receive the error toast message?

Comment: nooo @SavanLuffy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Authentication doesn't store the user credentials in the Firebase database.

If the user credentials are stored in the database, it's because your application code stores it there. You will need to update it in the database by running the same code as you ran when you saved the credentials in the database initially.

Something like this could for example update the password:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users/Driver")
    .child(uid).child("password").setValue("new password");
```

Note: it is a **really** bad idea to store the user's credentials in clear text like you're doing, and I **highly** recommend leaving it to Firebase Authentication to store that data securely for you.

Comment: The part where u wrote setValue("new password") how do i get access to the new password ?

Comment: Also as u mentioned  i stored it in realtime database because i have a page called profile from where user can read his information
and idk how to retrieve those value from firebase auththentication

Comment: It sounds like the password is being (re)set outside of your application code, in which case there's no way for your application code to access it. In my opinion that is a Good Thing, as (as said in my answer too) you really should not be saving the user's credentials in your database - but leave that (only) to Firebase Authentication.

Comment: Hey @MohammadYusuf. Anything else needed here?

Comment: heyy yea now everything is  working i removed it from realtime database tx for help